# Is it illegal to use an illustration of me as a LEGO minifigure on my website?

Tags: minifigures, lego-group

I created an education web platform with different activities so I have have made my LEGO illustration representing me in the different contexts of my site: classroom, consulting workshop room, lecture room, book club. As I became LSP certified facilitator, I have just read tonight that we are not allowed to use almost anything with LEGO TM especially minifigures. Can anyone help with more information? How to contact the legal department of Lego, persons in charge of brand?

Answer (score 5):

First, I need to state that we're not affiliated with The LEGO Group, but we are an officially Recognised LEGO Fan Media outlet, and that I'm not a lawyer.

The best I can suggest is reading through the LEGO Group's [Fair Play statement](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/legal/notices-and-policies/fair-play/) and note the FAQ on the [Serious Play section](https://www.lego.com/en-us/seriousplay/faq) of their site:

> **What is meant with “iconic and/or emphasized use of the LEGO minifigures and/or the LEGO bricks/knobs is not allowed” according to the Trademark Guidelines?**
> It means that enhanced/stand-alone use of the LEGO® minifigure, the LEGO® brick or the knob configuration/pattern – i.e. as a business identifier/logo/sign or as an eye catching design element on various materials/web sites etc. – is not allowed. Only the LEGO Group can use the trademarks as source indicators, meaning an indication of origin of a service or a product. The knob configuration/pattern is typically used by the LEGO Group as background on a website, on a book cover or displayed on license products.

And the [full guidelines can be found here (PDF)](https://www.lego.com/r/www/r/portals/-/media/campaigns/grownup/serious-play2/lego-serious-play-trademark-guidelines-version-2017.pdf?la=en-US&l.r=-1821153426).

Finally, in terms of contacting them, you could start with their [Contact page](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/email-us/choose-topic), either "LEGO Company | Information about the LEGO Group" or "LEGO Company | Anything Else".

Comment: Thank you Zhaph-Ben Duguid. I’ve found yesterday night these guidelines...I will surely write to them today. There is no legal e-mail address bit I suppose they will transfer my demand to the right department.